# To anyone who is familiar with AdventureWorks, do these questions make sense?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, adventureworks

1. Show the company name for 'James D.Kramer'.
2. Show all addresses listed for 'Modular Cycle Systems'
3. Show order quantity, the name and the list price of the order made by 'CustomerID 635'

Code snippets:

```
--use [AdventureWorks2016CTP3]

--CAN'T get the required company with this name.
select 
    [BusinessEntityID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName] 
from 
    [Person].[Person]
where  
    [FirstName] = 'James' and 
    [MiddleName] = 'D.' and
    [LastName] = 'Kramer'



--Addresses for Modular Cycle Systems
select
    [Name], PeA.[AddressLine1] as [Address]
from 
    [Sales].[Store] as SaS
inner join 
    [Person].[BusinessEntityAddress] as PeBEA on SaS.BusinessEntityID = PeBEA.BusinessEntityID
inner join 
    [Person].[Address] as PeA on PeBEA.[AddressID] = PeA.[AddressID]
where 
    [Name] = 'Modular Cycle Systems'


--Details of CustomerID 635 - Apparently INCORRECT accorrdin to my Superior.
select 
    SaC.[CustomerID], SaSOD.[OrderQty], SaS.[Name], SaSOD.[UnitPrice] as ListPrice
from
    [Sales].[Customer] as SaC
join 
    sales.Store as SaS on SaC.StoreID = SaS.BusinessEntityID
join 
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as SaSOH on SaC.[CustomerID] = SaSOH.[CustomerID]
join 
    [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] as SaSOD on SaSOH.SalesOrderID = SaSOD.SalesOrderID
where 
    SaC.[CustomerID] = '635'
```

The parts which work:

```
Select 
    SaC.[CustomerID], [StoreID], SaS.[Name]
from
    [Sales].[Customer] as SaC
join
    [Sales].[Store] as SaS on SaS.BusinessEntityID = SaC.StoreID
where 
    SaC.[CustomerID] = '635'


select 
    SaSOH.[SalesOrderID], SaSOH.[CustomerID], 
    SaSOD.[OrderQty], SaSOD.[UnitPrice], SaSOD.[UnitPriceDiscount] 
from
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as SaSOH
join 
    [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] as SaSOD on SaSOH.[SalesOrderID] = SaSOD.[SalesOrderID]
```

--WORKS! without customer constraint though. 
--Meaning different transaction by the same customer/sales agent?

```
Select SaC.[CustomerID], [StoreID], SaS.[Name], 
    SaSOD.[OrderQty], SaSOD.[UnitPrice]
from [Sales].[Customer] as SaC
    Join [Sales].[Store] as SaS
        on SaS.BusinessEntityID = SaC.StoreID
    join [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] as SaSOH
        on SaSOH.[CustomerID] = SaC.[CustomerID]
    join [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] as SaSOD
        on SaSOH.[SalesOrderID] = SaSOD.[SalesOrderID]
where SaC.[StoreID] = '1960'
--and SaC.[CustomerID] = '635'
order by SaC.StoreID
```

Comment: show what is your expected result for each query

Comment: First questions during an internship. Not accepting no results or even NULL results :/ . I'm given just this and expected to work with it. And then show an output. So was asking whether question 1 and 3 even make sense to people familiar with AW.

Comment: For the first question ,sql query u written is wrong you have to display name of the comapny

Comment: I'm unable to get it. Can you please tell me how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first question:**

```
SELECT * FROM SALES.vStoreWithContacts
where FirstName = 'James'
and MiddleName = 'D.'
and LastName = 'Kramer'
```

---

```
BusinessEntityID    Name                            FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
1264                Refined Department Stores       Mr. James   D.          Kramer
```

In Person. Person table, James's BusinessentityID is 1263, which is different from 1264 in StoreContactTable. That is why you got nothing. But he is the owner of 'Refined Department Stores' if you look at the SALES.vStoreWithContacts separately.

**For the second question:** your query works fine.

**For the third question:**

The customer 645 did not place any order

```
select * from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where CustomerID = '635'
```

It returned nothing.

Comment: Do you have any idea how the CustomerID and StoreID map? Cause i do get a result with a storeID using sales.customer and sales.store. And i get some results when i use the StoreID as a filter instead. Don't know where i'm going wrong but can't get my head around why there's different results.. Thanks for your reply though, works for me.

Comment: @RohanTeja when you use the storeID as filter, you got different results because there are many customers buying items from that StoreID

Comment: So, CustomerID is for sales between a particular store and Adventure works while StoreID is for those transactions for resales between the said store to other individual customers? Thanks for the clarification even though these questions feel too beginner  to me myself.

Comment: @RohanTeja  No worry. Every expert was once a beginner. I highly suggest you read the intro of AdventureWorks. Imagine you are their SQL developer. (That is fun). Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms124825(v=sql.100)

Answer (score 0):

First question i changed the person name ,try this query

```
SELECT st.[BusinessEntityID],st.Name AS CompanyName
       ,[FirstName]
       ,[MiddleName]
       ,[LastName]  
FROM Sales.Store st
INNER JOIN sales.Customer cu
ON cu.StoreID = st.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN [Person].[Person] p
on p.[BusinessEntityID] = cu.PersonID
WHERE p.[FirstName] = 'Amy' and 
    p.[MiddleName] = 'E.' and
    p.[LastName] = 'Alberts'
```

Comment: I know this works but I specifically need it for James D.Cramer..Thanks for the trail though. My first try was the same but don't get any row output..

Comment: @RohanTeja Hi your not catching my point  ,if don't get result for James D.Cramer means he don't have matching records while joining the tables,because of that  i changes to "Alberts"

Comment: I understood your point. But does that mean he doesn't belong to any company? Also, do you have any idea about what's wrong with part 3?

Answer (score 0):

They are completely valid questions.

I can't emphasise enough: You're going to be quickly identified as a valuable employee if you can *problem solve*

Your responses indicate you haven't done any problem solving at all.

> > CAN'T get the required company with this name

and

> > Unable to get it

When you haven't defined the actual issue, it means you haven't even started problem solving. Do you get 0 rows? The wrong rows? Too many rows?

One of the most useful tools in problem solving is *break it into little bits and isolate which bit doesn't work*. So for example for your first issue:

```
select 
    [BusinessEntityID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName] 
from 
    [Person].[Person]
where  
    [FirstName] = 'James' and 
    [MiddleName] = 'D.' and
    [LastName] = 'Kramer'
```

I'm going to assume "Can't get it" means you got no rows.

So do some problem solving:

Firstly are there any rows to start with? Check:

```
select 
    [BusinessEntityID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName] 
from 
    [Person].[Person]
```

If there are rows, then just try your `WHERE` clause in pieces and see which bit is failing:

```
select 
    [BusinessEntityID], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName] 
from 
    [Person].[Person]
where  
    [FirstName] = 'James'
```

Does this return anything?

Comment: Love the help and the structured manner of your answer but no, i already tried the simple queries. Yes, i will get a result for part one and i didn't try part two, but similar to what sreenu wrote; my code does work for some other names. I think that the specified name has no company..But thanks still, i did get your point.